# Makefile Loops: "command not found error" popping before the loop begins, but working fine afterward

Tags: makefile

I want to run a program with increasing input sizes, so I introduced a `run` target that contains a loop.

```
run:
    input_size = 1000 ; while [[ $$input_size -le 10000 ]] ; do \
        echo $$input_size ; \
        ./main.out $$input_size ; \
        ((input_size = input_size + 1000)) ; \
    done
```

I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: input_size: command not found
```

after which, the loop works as expected.

Comment: What problem do you want to solve here? Doesn't look like the normal usage of a makefile. A shell script might be more suitable. BTW: this is not at all related to C language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your makefile has several issues, if we fix your version, it should be:

```
run:
    input_size=1000 ; while [ $$input_size -le 10000 ] ; do \
        echo $$input_size ; \
        ./main_out $$input_size ; \
        input_size=$$((input_size + 1000)) ; \
    done
```

An easier method for generating sequences of numbers is the use of `seq`:

```
run:
    for input_size in $$(seq 1000 1000 10000); do  \
    echo $$input_size ; \
    ./main_out $$input_size ; \
    done
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped me have a lot more cleaner code.

Comment: Is there a way to suppress the loop from bring output to the console?

Comment: @NikhilCSB Just place an @ before the first char (i.e. @input_size....)

Comment: /bin/sh: `@input_size': not a valid identifier

Comment: Use `make -s` to suppress the output. Although, it does not suppress the output of the program being called, which was what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

In `bash` there must be no space around the assignment symbol (unlike `make`):

```
input_size=1000
```

Alternatively, you can use bash arithmetic expansion, which is more relaxed about whitespace:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

run:
    for (( input_size = 1000; input_size < 10000; input_size += 1000 )); do \
        echo $$input_size; \
    done
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped me have a cleaner code.

Comment: I'm getting `unexpected end of file` with `.ONESHELL:`

Comment: @NikhilCSB I think you misplaced your comment. I suggest you try my example.

Comment: I'm sorry, which example?

Comment: @NikhilCSB The one you leave your comments under.

Comment: Will `SHELL := /bin/bash` be applicable to every target that comes under it? If yes, how do I end its effect?

Comment: @NikhilCSB Here is the doc: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-SHELL

Answer (score 1):

Just to be very clear about the problem you have:

The problem is that make doesn't run recipes using whatever shell the user has: that would be a disaster for repeatable builds.  make always (by the POSIX standard) runs recipes in the `/bin/sh` shell which is a POSIX shell.

Your recipes are using enhanced features of the `bash` shell, which are not available in POSIX shell.  You need to either rewrite your recipes to use POSIX shell features, or else explicitly request that make use `bash` to run your recipes instead of the POSIX shell (of course this means your makefile is not portable to any system where `bash` is not available, if this is a concern).

You can do the latter by adding this to your makefile:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
```